# USB to ethernet: fail to transmit any packages

Tags: networking, embedded, buildroot

I have a custom embedded linux board with a lan7500i-ABZJ connected over USB.

So I compiled the linux kernel (using buildroot) with the smsc75xx module built in. The startup kernel messages indeed show:

```
    [    5.315124] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=7500, bcdDevice= 2.00
    [    5.324072] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    5.340746] smsc75xx v1.0.0
    [    5.539195] smsc75xx 1-1:1.0 eth1: register 'smsc75xx' at usb-ci_hdrc.0-1, smsc75xx USB 2.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 8e:64:f6:eb:5e:65
```

Now I add an IP address:

```
    ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.44 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

But once I try to ping an address on the local network, all packets are lost:

```
    # ping 192.168.1.40
    PING 192.168.1.40 (192.168.1.40): 56 data bytes
    ^C
    --- 192.168.1.40 ping statistics ---
    3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
    # arp
    ? (192.168.1.40) at <incomplete>  on eth1
```

And no packages are transmitted over the interface:

```
    eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8E:64:F6:EB:5E:65  
              inet addr:192.168.1.44  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

No other network interfaces are active. A ping to localhost works, so I assume everything is OK on TCP/IP level. Why can't I use my ethernet interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifconfig` (or here probably `busybox ifconfig`) displays `RUNNING` in addition to `UP` for a NIC which is both administratively UP and has detected a carrier (ie: a remote NIC, switch etc.). The lack of `RUNNING` means the NIC is not connected or couldn't be set in such a way as to properly detect the NIC on the other side of the wire.

`ip link` (or `busybox ip link`), which on Linux should always be preferred (along with `ip address`) over `ifconfig`, would have displayed the unmistakable `NO-CARRIER` flag in this case.

So you'll have to check why there is no carrier. Usually the `ethtool` command comes in handy here, to see if auto negotiation failed, or must not be used etc. If not already present, you should add it to the build.